# How to create an endpoint that does not require authentication in Api-Platform?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to define an endpoint called “share as guest” which allows someone to share content without logging in.
All that this endpoint needs to do is return content data without requiring authentication.

But it came a bit tricky with [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/), most of, because it contains an `id` param in the endpoint and is an **Item operation**, not a Collection.

As of defining it in security ymal file I used [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857736/symfony-access-control-with-variable-inside-route) reference:

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/content/[0-9]+/share-as-guest, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/token/refresh, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/users, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
    ...
```

And for defining it within API platform in `.xml` file:

```
    <itemOperation name="share_as_guest">
            <attribute name="path">/api/content/{id}/share-as-guest.{_format}</attribute>
            <attribute name="method">GET</attribute>
            <attribute name="output">App\UI\ContentView</attribute>
            <attribute name="security">is_granted('PUBLIC_ACCESS')</attribute>
     </itemOperation>
```

It is explained well [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73699708/api-platform-public-custom-api).

When trying to trigger it without the line in yml file I get `401 JWT Token not found`
And with it: `404 Not Found`

It this the right way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: I've got the same problem. I will let you know when i've found a solution.